# Getting id of not active nav-pill

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a web page which has a markup like (**simplified for the question**)

```
<div>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#first" data-toggle="tab">One</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#second" data-toggle="tab">second</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#third" data-toggle="tab">third</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="first"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="second"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="third"></div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the id of the **.tab-pane:not(.active)**. To achieve this on click event I have the following code

```
var notActivePane = $(".tab-pane:not(.active)").find(".input-validation-error").closest('.tab-pane:not(.active)').get(0).id;
```

I keep getting `undefined`

this is the actual final markup from the page

[image]

Comment: That's because all the `.tab-pane` elements have the `active` class, so `$(".tab-pane:not(.active)")` returns nothing

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan my apologies that was a typo in the quesiton, I've updated it

Comment: Ok, in that case are you sure those elements contain a `.input-validation-error` element?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the `.input-validation-error` will be on first two divs if any of the required fields is not filled in. The third one will not contain is as all inputs are optionals

Comment: So the class is added to the element, not within it? If so `find()` isn't going to work. You could just select by that element. It would be more helpful if you could add some HTML that's already in the state you're trying to work with

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I've updated my question to include the html

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) 
{ 
    //do your job
}
```

Comment: I need to check which `tab-pane` has got  `.input-validation-error` class and then get the id of that so I can open that tab

Comment: Yes in this way you can select all the classes that do not have active class and then find the .input-validation-error

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/):

```
console.log($('.input-validation-error').parents('.tab-pane'));
```

```js
$(function() {
  //This works for cases when only one tab has inputs with .input-validation-error
  console.log($('.input-validation-error').parents('.tab-pane:not(.active)').attr('id'));

  //To get all tabs with errors that dont have class active
  var tabsWithErrors = $('.input-validation-error').parents('.tab-pane:not(.active)');
  tabsWithErrors.each(function(index, element) {
    console.log($(element).attr('id'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#first" data-toggle="tab">One</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#second" data-toggle="tab">second</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#third" data-toggle="tab">third</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="first">
    <div>
      <div>
        <input class="form-control input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Ink Reference Code field is required." id="InkReferenceCode" name="InkReferenceCode" type="text" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="second">
    <div>
      <div>
        <input class="form-control input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Ink Manufacturer field is required." id="InkManufacturer" name="InkManufacturer" type="text" value="">
        <input class="form-control input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Ink Reference Code field is required." id="InkReferenceCode" name="InkReferenceCode" type="text" value=""></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="third">
    <div>
      <div>
        <input class="form-control input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Ink Manufacturer field is required." id="InkManufacturer" name="InkManufacturer" type="text" value="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I get the id of `.parents('.tab-pane'));`

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Weirdly I'm still getting `undefined`. Would it matter if the input is not directly under the `<div class=tab-pane id=second></div>`. Because it's actually two more divs down so `div class=tab-pane id=second><div><div>MY INPUT</div></div></div>`.

Comment: It doesn't matter how nested the input is. I have edited my answer to include said markup. There's probably something wrong with your HTML. Can you post EXACTLY what you have :)

Comment: I've added an image of the HTML, can you please have a look for me

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle demo that represents your problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135949/discussion-between-code-and-ivanka-todorova).